# I'm getting an error in python seaborn : AttributeError: Rectangle.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hist'

Tags: python, seaborn

My code:

```
sns.displot(df["sex"], hist=False)
plt.show()
```

I expected a converted histogram graph with no bars.

Answer (score 2):

You're using old reference of function `seaborn.distplot`. It has been [deprecated](https://gist.github.com/mwaskom/de44147ed2974457ad6372750bbe5751).

Use `sns.kdeplot(df["sex"])`
or  `sns.displot(df["sex"], kind="kde")`

Comment: I am not using distplot. I am using displot and its working but when using 'hist' parameter it is showing error.

Comment: Theres no such parameter as hist. Hist was a parameter of distplot, it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `hist` parameter in `displot()` function.

here is the definition:

```
seaborn.displot(data=None, *, x=None, y=None, hue=None, row=None, col=None, weights=None, kind='hist', rug=False, rug_kws=None, log_scale=None, legend=True, palette=None, hue_order=None, hue_norm=None, color=None, col_wrap=None, row_order=None, col_order=None, height=5, aspect=1, facet_kws=None, **kwargs)
```

Link to doc:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html